# extract dictionaries from a list of dictionaries ( based on a condition from (key, value))

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a **list of dictionaries** such as:

```
data_list = [
    {"AB":1.23,  'height':60.0}, 
    {"AB":1.23,  'height':61.0}, 
    {"AB":1.23,  'height':60.0},
    {"AC":2.60,  'height':60.0},
    {"AC":2.60,  'height':62.0},
    {"AC":2.60,  'height':60.0},
]
```

**Based on a different value of key "height" (the same height related dictionary is taken once),**

I am looking for the **output** as follows:

```
data_list = [
   [{"AB":1.23,  'height':60.0}, 
    {"AB":1.23,  'height':61.0}, 
    {"AC":2.60,  'height':60.0},
    {"AC":2.60,  'height':62.0},]
```

Here is my try:

```
data_list = [
    {"AB":1.23,  'height':60.0}, 
    {"AB":1.23,  'height':61.0}, 
    {"AB":1.23,  'height':60.0},
    {"AC":2.60,  'height':60.0},
    {"AC":2.60,  'height':62.0},
    {"AC":2.60,  'height':60.0},
    ]

print(data_list)

new_data_list = []
for ii, idict in enumerate(data_list):
    for jj, jdict in enumerate(data_list):
        if jj >= ii+1: 
            if idict['height'] != jdict['height']:
                new_data_list.append(idict)
print(new_data_list)
```

How to obtain the required output?

Comment: You need to make it clear exactly how the output values are selected from the input list.

Comment: Just select the dictionary based on different height in the second "key" of each dictionary. Hoping that it is clear.

Comment: So why is it `{"AB":1.23,  'height':60.0}` and not `{"AB":4.32,  'height':60.0}`?

Comment: Any one of them is fine for me. The point is to have the same "height". May be it is better to change the dict data to make it more clear.

Comment: This would be an easier problem to solve if your dicts were of the form `{ 'name' : 'AB', 'value' : 1.23, 'height' : 60.0 }`. Are there guaranteed to only be two keys in the dict?

Comment: It does make it easier, as you don't have to figure out what the non-height key is. But it is solvable as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by creating a `set` of all the heights seen for each key, and only appending a dict to the result if the `height` has not been seen before. A [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) can simplify the code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data_list = [
    {"AB":1.23,  'height':60.0}, 
    {"AB":1.23,  'height':61.0}, 
    {"AB":1.23,  'height':60.0},
    {"AC":2.60,  'height':60.0},
    {"AC":2.60,  'height':62.0},
    {"AC":2.60,  'height':60.0},
]

heights = defaultdict(set)
result = []
for d in data_list:
    k = [k for k in d.keys() if k != 'height'][0]
    if not d['height'] in heights[k]:
        heights[k].add(d['height'])
        result.append(d)
```

Output:

```
[
 {'AB': 1.23, 'height': 60.0},
 {'AB': 1.23, 'height': 61.0},
 {'AC': 2.6, 'height': 60.0},
 {'AC': 2.6, 'height': 62.0}
]
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?